# How can I force gnuparallel to carry out a command set sequentially?

Tags: linux, bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

Gnu parallel is a powerful tool that I use to run many independant BASH commands as a single set in parallel. I would like to be able to run the same commands SEQUENTIALLY without significant changes to the command I use. I know there is a switch to force the output to be returned as THOUGH run sequentially but I would like to have gnuparallel ACTUALLY RUN sequentially. My reason is for testing purposes on a machine which has a tendancy to overheat, solving my hardware issue is not an option, furthermore one could potentially imagine other testing regimes for which running gnuparallel sequentially would be useful.

So. Is there a way to simply run gnuparallel sequentially or would I need to manually unpack the gnuparallel command set into its component commands and run those in sequence?

Comment: If the purpose of the program is to take advantage of parallelism of cores/threads, then it kinda defeats the point to ask it to behave in a serial manner.  If you want the commands to be executed in a serial manner, then they can just be scripted without using parallel.

Comment: @killermist If you have a long command that you want to give one arg at a time, but want to run it serially, then it may be shorter to build the command using GNU Parallel.

Comment: Heh.  I use bash `for` loops to do that.  `for argument in this that other something; do /usr/bin/somecommand --flaghere "$argument" other_"$argument"; done`  Easy.

Comment: @OleTange has the idea. One may want their processes to run sequentially but still wish to use the powerful syntax of GNU Parallel.

Comment: @killermist Here using GNU Parallel: `parallel /usr/bin/somecommand --flaghere {} other_{} ::: this that other something` # Somewhat shorter and less quoting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `parallel` man page says that the `--jobs` option (same as `-j`, `--max-procs` and `-P`) specifies the number of jobs run in parallel. So, executing `parallel` with `--jobs 1` should run your jobs in sequence.

Comment: I thought there would be a switch but hadn't looked at the options from your perspective. This solution will allow dynamic selection of how many concurrent processes to run. It answers my question even better than I had hoped.

Comment: For extra dynamic use `-j file` and change the content of `file` while GNU Parallel is running.

Comment: However, I made the experience that `-j1` not only limits the number of parallel jobs to 1 but also limits the currently running job to a single core. Whereas running the same job locally on my computer uses all available cores.

Can I somehow enforce sequential execution but allow each job to use multiple cores in parallel?